# Where to put Event listener to detect afterSave of plugin table (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm on CakePHP 3.3.16
I've put this in the main app's Bootstrap.php:

```
Log::write('info','foo');
$contactTable = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Contacts.contacts');
$contactTable->eventManager()
       ->on('Model.afterSave', ['priority' => 1],function($event, $entity)
       {
           pr( "afterSave - " );
           Log::write('info','afterSave');

       });
```

I do get "foo" in the lofs, and yet when I save the plugin model in question, there's nothing in the logs. I've tried with and without priority.

Do I need to update CakePHP?  I think a method has been depracated? The CakePHP event docs said to place this code in Bootstrap.php, so I'm confused...

Comment: The instance of the table you are calling is lower-case 'Contacts.contacts', the convention is that Tables are capitalized Camel-Case in the registry..... you may have a scoping issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  I did try $contactTable->get('12') and it did return an entity, so I thought 'Contacts.contacts' was fine.